# How to plot only certain values of continuous variables using `sjPlot::plot_model()`

Tags: r, plot, interaction-plot

I'm using the `plot_model()` function in R to visualize an interaction for an OLS regression.
The regression is:
`model <- lm(dv ~ condition + control1 + control2 + variable1 + condition*variable1, data=data)`
condition is a 4-level factor variable.
variable1 is a continuous variable.
control1 is a continuous variable.
control2 is a factor variable with 2-levels.

I'm trying to visualize the interaction of this regression, with variable1 on the x-axis, and condition as indicators.
However, I'm hoping to visualize it as if variable 1 was a factor variable, i.e., only showing particular points (2, 4, and 6) on the plot, with confidence interval whiskers, instead of a straight line across all continuous values and confindence interval bands around the line.  So something that looks like this:

[image]

Rather than this:
[image]

I've tried multiple things but am having trouble looking for the right solution. Any help will be appreciated! The code I have now that creates the line & band plot is:

```
plot_model(model, type="pred",terms=c("variable1","condition"), ci.lvl=0.95)
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Specify the points your want in brackets in the `terms` argument:

```
library(sjPlot)

model <- lm(hwy ~ year + drv * displ, data = ggplot2::mpg)

plot_model(model, type = "pred", terms = c("drv",  "displ [2, 3, 5]"))
```

[image]